# Compare strings correctly in C

Tags: c, string, if-statement

I have to make a program where the input must be one of 2 values, 'M' or 'F'.

Here is the program segment that I have created to demonstrate

```
do
{

     printf("What is your Gender? (M for Male - F for Female) "); 
     fgets(GenderValue, 16, stdin); 

     if (GenderValue[0] == '\n') 
     {
           printf("Try again");
           getch();
           system("cls");
           loop=1;
     }
     else
     {
           loop = -1;
     }
     if (GenderValue == "M");
     {
          loop =-1;
     }
     else if(GenderValue == "F");
     {
          loop=-1;
     }

     else
     {
           printf("Try again");
           getch();
           system("cls");
           loop=1;
     }



 }
 while(loop > 0); //Checks for NULL input

 printf("Gender: %s",GenderValue);
```

I know I could have done an integer choice input, but I would like to recycle this later if possible.

So far the program calls my Gender value comparisons "Errors", Which is fine, except I have no idea what to do next, I could find a function that compares strings, but I really don't want to over complicate my code.

Edit: Duplicate?, Really?, The example given doesn't even come close to helping me.

Edit 2: Found the problem, i had ;'s next to my if statements, that's fixed now. But seriously, no one spotted this ?

Comment: How is `GenderValue` declared?

Comment: "So far the program calls my Gender value comparisons "Errors", Which is fine". Not, actually. 1. These are *compiler errors*, 2. and you should at least show the first one. They usually also come with line numbers -- the compiler tells you *what* is wrong and *where*.

Comment: `GenderValue[0] == 'M'` or ``GenderValue[0] == 'F'`` can also be used

Comment: @Santosh it's formatted as a string.

Comment: remove your first `else` condition, because if you enter any character it will make `loop = -1;` and you will exit `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If `GenderValue` is a string,  `GenderValue == "M"` is wrong . strings are not supposed to be comapred with `==`. use [`strcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp).
2. [In this case, IMO its suitable] If `GenderValue` is a single character, comparison should be done as `GenderValue == 'M'`

For your case, [considering one character input] you can do something like

```
fgets(GenderValue, 16, stdin);
switch(GenderValue[0])
{
   case '\n':
              //your code
              break;
   case 'M':
   case 'm':
                //your code
              break;
   case 'F':
   case 'f':
                //your code
              break;                  
   default:
}
```

In above code, three advantages

- You don't need to bother about removing trailing `\n` caused by
  `fgets()`
- Exactly one character input is considered
- No need to worry about the upper/lower case of input.

Answer (score 6):

You use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) to compare strings. Using the comparison operator `==` just compares the *pointers*.

But note that [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) will leave the ending newline in the string, so you need to compare to e.g. `"M\n"`, or remove the newline if it's there.

Also note that `scrcmp` is *case sensitive*, the string `"M"` is not equal to the string `"m"`.

---

You could use e.g. [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to read the input as a single character instead, and use e.g. [`tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower) (or [`toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper)) to get case insensitive comparison.

However, using `scanf` brings other problems, especially if you use it again afterwards to read another single character. The reason for this is that `Scanf` leaves the newline in the input buffer, causeing the possible next `scanf` call with the `"%c"` format to read that newline. There are *very* simple solution for this: Tell `scanf` to read and discart leading whitespace by using `" %c"`.

Answer (score 1):

replace  `(GenderValue == "M")` with `(strcmp(GenderValue, "M") == 0 )`

and

replace  `(GenderValue == "F")` with `(strcmp(GenderValue, "F") == 0 )`

Comment: without removing the `\n` from `GenderValue`, this won't work.

Comment: Or i could compare "M\n", either way my program is still pulling a fit

Answer (score 0):

try replacing `GenderValue == "F"` with `!strcmp(GenderValue, "F\n")` and `GenderValue == "M"` with `!strcmp(GenderValue, "M\n")`

you might also need to include `"string.h"`

Comment: So my if statement would be exactly the same?

Comment: well, I am not sure what exactly you want to do. at first glance, the first else should not be there because it sets loop to -1 and even if the conditions that follow hold, this wont change.

Comment: I want the statements to only allow M and F. GenderValue is a string.

Comment: there are several nice solutions that were proposed by other people; if you do not want to change your code too much, just remove the three lines after the first else.

The new code should be something like:
else if (!strcmp(GenderValue, "M\n"))

Comment: I should be fine with the help i got above, the case statement above is proving rather effective.

Answer (score 0):

Use string compare function (strcmp("")) whenever you need to compare strings.